# why do I get an EJBTransactionRolledbackException when I call two DAOs in my EJB Service?

Tags: java, ejb

I'm using IBM RAD 7.5 and WebSphere 7.

I have an EJB (@Stateless CustomerService), and I have two EJBs that are DAOs (@Stateless CustomerDAO and @Stateless OrderDAO).

My method in CustomerService works fine when I do customerDAO.getAll().

But if I call customerDAO.getAll() and then orderDAO.getByCustomerId(int id), the second getAll throws an EJBTransactionRolledBackException.

Why does this happen, and how to prevent it?

Thanks, Rob

## update with code

I have this following ...

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerService
  @EJB
  private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
  @EJB
  private OrderDAO orderDAO;

  public void myMethod() {
    List<Customer> customers = customerDAO.getAll();
    for (Customer c : customers) {
      List<Order> orders = orderDAO.getByCustomerId(c.getId());
      /*** THIS THROWS EJBTransactionRolledBackException ***/
    }
  }
```

... and my DAOs look like this ...

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerDAO
  @PersistenceUnit
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
  }

  public List<Customer> getAll() {
    try {
      em = getEntityManager();
      Query query = em.createQuery(" /*...*/ ");
      query.getResultList();
    } finally {
      em.close();
    }
  }
```

... and ...

```
@Stateless
public class OrderDAO
  @PersistenceUnit
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
  }

  public List<Customer> getByCustomerId(int customerid) {
    try {
      em = getEntityManager();
      Query query = em.createQuery(" /*...*/ ");
      /* ... */
      query.getResultList();
    } finally {
      em.close();
    }
  }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks, Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you have an issue with your EJB transaction demarcations.  Firstly, your DAOs should not be EJBs.  EJBs should be used at the service layer where one of the main advantages is declarative transaction management.  By making your DAOs EJBs, you are engaging container managed transaction operations at the DAO method level.

If you provide your dao code and configuration, we can make a more definitive assessment.

Comment: Thanks.  Currently the DAOs are EJBs and the Service gets a reference injected via the @EJB annotation.  If the DAOs are no EJBs, should I just do a MyDAO dao = new MyDAO in the EJB code?  Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how your DAOs are configured (e.g. how are you getting a handle to a DB connection, etc.),  or are you using Spring?

Comment: Hi -- I added sample code to my question (above).  Also, I looked at a couple example I have (online and in a book) and both have the "DAOs" marked as @Stateles too, so I think that's appropriate?

Comment: where are you instantiating your EntityManager (em) in your DAOs?

Comment: Yes, in the DAO.  I added the "getEntityManager" method to the code samples above.  Thanks!

Comment: Did some more digging. It turns out it wasn't the orderDAO.getAll() that was causing the exception, it was a orderDAO.getByCustomerId(id) -- I'm now assuming that the transaction exception is causes because there's a OneToMany and ManyToOne relationship between the two entities Customer and Order. In trying to load the Order, it must also be trying to load the associated Customer which is conflicting with the previous Customer.getAll call -- I'll have to work on this, either remove the OneToMany relationship or do some kind of EAGER fetching on the Customer's Orders. Thanks. (more edits)